# Trying to target Moto G and Samsung Galaxy S4 using Media Query

Tags: android, css, media-queries

I am confused about the width of the phones that I am trying to target for media query.

```
1. Samsung Galaxy S4  4.99in phone screen width 360px
```

and the other one

```
2. Moto G 4.5in phone screen width 360px.
```

How can target these phones separately ? . I tried following code but it effects both the phone similarly

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 540px)  and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */


}

@media screen and (device-width: 541px)  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
{
}
```

Can any one will clarify this to me . What I am not able to understand is that both the phones have different size screen but how can they be same width 360 ??

Thanks & Regards

Comment: To target Samsung Galaxy S4 use this `@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)`

Comment: @KheemaPandey  Yes I got that . but not able to target Moto G

Comment: I didn;t found any specific media query for MOTO G. Might be you have to do some R&D. but if you found solution please post her as well. so people looking for same can get solution.

Comment: I found this for MOTO G `@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)`. let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is for the pixel density of each device.

**“Pixel density”** is the number of pixels a display can fit into a fixed distance. This is different from “resolution”, which is a simple count of the number of pixels across the entire width and height of a device.

If we divide the physical width of the display by the number of pixels displayed horizontally, the result is the number of pixels per inch (ppi, also commonly referred to as dpi).

So even though these device are sharing the same resolution width, the samsung galaxy S4 has more pixels for the same width and therefore its pixel density is higher and their media queries are different.

**SAMSUNG GALAXY S4**

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 360px) and @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 9/16)
```

**MOTO G**

`@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)`

Comment: I tried using the same Moto G solution provided by KheemaPandey but it does not work I have both the phones with me

Comment: Ok, there might be some small issue in the resolution. Let me see if i can fix it :)

Comment: If you are testing on the real device, try adding some different background colours to see if they get triggered inside those 2 different media queries. Also add some js to see which is your device width and height.

Comment: I suggest you trying to find the specific device-aspect-ratio for Motorola Moto G and you are set. That's what you are looking for to make those 2 media queries more specific.

Comment: yes right I think if I get the aspect ratio of the Moto G I am all set by the way for S$ its no problem it working fine with `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2`

Answer (score -1):

Here is the specific media query to target the both devices individually. **[This link](http://www.canbike.org/CSSpixels/)** is very helpful.

**Samsung S4**

```
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
```

**MOTO G**

```
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

Comment: I tried for the MoTo G soloution its not working tested on chrome Browser but the link is really helpful thanks explains everything. Note: I have used this code in the header `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">`

Comment: Are you testing on simulator or with real device?

Comment: I have both the device Moto G and S4 with me right now

Comment: What if you add `only screen and (min-resolution: 326dpi)` its for MOTOG

Comment: lets try with that. and share your input.. Its really going very good conversation and good learning as well..

Comment: That's why stackoverflow is a great place to share IT knowledge :)

Comment: wait let me test it :)

Comment: @KheemaPandey no still not targeting the moto g

Comment: so giving the resolution also not solving..  did you use 329dpi? Will look at it..

Answer (score -2):

I have similar issue and I used below code to fix

```
@media (max-width: 361px) {
/* CSS Classes */
}
```

webkit-device-pixel-ratio didn't work for me, don't know for what reason though.

Also refer the below URL for more reference.
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/mediaqueries/mobile.html